# what am I missing in this proof?

Tags: analysis

2 part proof, the authors proof seems over-complicated to me, which makes me think I am missing something.

**(A)** if $m,n,p,q$ are integers, $n>0$, $q>0$, $r=m/n=p/q$, prove that $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$. Hence it makes sense to define $b^r=(b^m)^{1/n}$

Solution provided : Let $r=\frac{m}{n}=\frac{p}{q}$. Then $mq=np$ and $((b^m)^{1/n})^{nq}=b^{mq}=b^{np}=((b^p)^{1/q})^{nq}$. Since roots are unique, it follows that $b^r=(b^m)^{1/n}$.

I don't get this proof. Is it the same to just write : Because $r=m/n=p/q$, $(b^m)^{1/n}=b^r=(b^p)^{1/q}=b^r$

Or, suppose $(b^m)^{1/n} \neq (b^p)^{1/q}$, given $r=m/n=p/q$, $(b^m)^{1/n}=b^r=(b^p)^{1/q}=b^r$. This is a contradiction. Thus, $(b^m)^{1/n}=(b^p)^{1/q}$

Why do you need the part about "since roots are unique"? Is something wrong with my proof? It feels like the proof is already contained in the definitions of the question...

**(b)** Prove that $b^{r+s}=b^r+b^s$ if $r$ and $s$ are rational. 
Proof given : let $r=m/n$ and $s=c/t$. Then, $$(b^{r+s})^{nt}=b^{mt+nc}=b^{mt}b^{nc}=((b^{mt})^{1/nt})^{nt}((b^{nc})^{1/nt})^{nt}\\=(b^{m/n})^{nt}(b^{c/t})^{nt}=(b^{r})^{nt}(b^{s})^{nt} = (b^rb^s)^{nt}$$

I don't understand why in this proof, the author takes for granted that $b^{mt+nc}=b^{mt}b^{nc}$ If this is given, then can you just write : $$b^{c/d + e/f}=b^{\frac{cf+de}{df}}=b^{\frac{cf}{df}}b^{\frac{de}{df}}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $(b^m)^{1/n}=b^r=(b^p)^{1/q}=b^r$

The issue is that you don't know that $b^r$ even makes sense, you are using the fact that it is well defined to prove that it is well defined.

Let us first understand the issue well. Take $b=3$ and $r=\frac{1}{2}$. **Why do we need to make sure that $3^r$ is well defined**? well the issue is the fact that $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{4}{8}$ but, $b^\frac{1}{2}, b^\frac{2}{4},b^\frac{3}{6}, b^\frac{4}{8}$ are defined in different ways:
$$3^{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{3} \\
3^{\frac{2}{4}}=\sqrt[4]{9} \\
3^{\frac{3}{6}}=\sqrt[6]{27}\\
3^{\frac{4}{8}}=\sqrt[8]{81}
$$

All these values should be $3^{\frac{1}{2}}$ but what if they are different? You need to show that they are equal.

**Note** Let us look at a a different operation on fractions to really understand the issue with your proof:

Lets define (I am picking one of the many possible un-defined operations) a "super multiplication by rationals" the following way: if $b$ is real and $r =\frac{m}{n}$ then 
$$b \circledast \frac{m}{n} = b \cdot m$$
(where $\cdot$ is standard multiplication).

Note that
$$3 \circledast \frac{1}{2} =3 \\
  3 \circledast \frac{2}{4}=6$$
Your above argument is that since $\frac{1}{2}=r=\frac{2}{4}$ then 
$$3 \circledast \frac{1}{2} = 3 \circledast r =3 \circledast \frac{2}{4}$$
but you can see that they are not equal.

**Conclusion** Any time you define an operation on rationals which depends on the fraction representation of the rational, you need to **first** prove that the operation is independent of the representation.

Comment: So, when in the original proof I guess the author converts the rational exponents to integer-products which don't have this problem. Thank you, now the authors proof makes much more sense to me. 

Does he need to say "since roots are unique"? What did he mean by that? Why is it necessary?

Comment: @Frank The author basically showed that the $nq$ powers of $((b^m)^{1/n})$ and $((b^p)^{1/q})$ are equal. In other words $((b^m)^{1/n})$ and $((b^p)^{1/q})$ are roots of some polynomial $$x^{nq}-a=0$$ Now, this polynomial has an unique positive root, thus both $((b^m)^{1/n})$ and $((b^p)^{1/q})$ must be equal to this positive root, and hence equal.

Comment: @Frank Note that positivity is important here. In real numbers and in complex numbers you can have the $nq$ power of two numbers being equal without the numbers being equal.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the author is using the natural exponents for the outer most powers and you are freely using rational exponents.

More than likely the author is trying to use the theorems which has been proved in the text about powers and you are jumping ahead and assuming some rules which have not been proved in text.